# android json to listview

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I working with android and JSON. I came so far, but I can's set the ID in the arraylist.The error will be in "json_data.getInt("ID")"

Can sombody help me

```
    public void klussenlijst()
    {
ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONObject json_data;
        mysql client = new mysql("http://www.****************/klussen.php?actie=klussen");

        try {
            client.Execute(RequestMethod.POST);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String response = client.getResponse();

        try{;
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
             for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
             json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
             results.add(json_data.getInt("ID"),(String) json_data.get("titel").toString());
            }
             filllist();


             }
             catch(JSONException e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

    }
```

Comment: There is no error in eclipse. Only when I but it in the android phone my program closes automaticly

Comment: Can you print out what "response" looks like to help us debug it better.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your mysql() method and the huge lack of error handling, but are you sure that your project has allowed for INTERNET permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file?  Sounds to me like your getInt is not an int.