# Retrieving the Json data into a list view

Tags: java, android, json

I've successfully done Httpclient using Get method and also form Json. Now I dont understand how to retrieve the Json data into a list view.

I googleed the code for an hour but I still don't understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on exactly how you want to handle the JSON. Try looking at [How to parse a JSON and turn its values into an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255220/java-how-to-parse-a-json-and-turn-its-values-into-an-array) once you have it parsed into an array just add the array elements to the listview.

Have a look at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html for how to add an array to the listview.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider the following threads:[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982700/parse-json-into-a-listview-friendly-output), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228033/parse-json-data-into-android-listview) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909646/android-json-to-listview).